# WSO2 ESB Clustering Architectural configuration

Tags: wso2, esb

i have a question about an architectural solution feasibility using WSO2.
This is my scenario:
I have a Web Service REST exposing some functionalities
I have the WSO2 ESB
I have a client layer (Liferay)

the architecture i want to develop is the one showed in the first image:
http://s11.postimg.org/gu6b6k3zn/Immagine.png

1) Liferay clients send request to avail one functionality
2) WSO2 ESB (clustered) get the client request... and (as a proxy) redirects it to che tomcat server by using load balancing mechanism
3) Web service on tomcat receives the request and answers to it

Studying the WSO2 documentation i saw the configuration showed in the img 2 dealing with esb clustering and load balancing
http://s17.postimg.org/tuy885gzz/Immagine2.png
As i can see, in this case the Tomcat Application Server(inside WSO2 AS) is embedded inside the WSO2 ESB, so i have to deploy my REST WS into the WSO2 esb, and then clustering it.
I want to ask if the second solution is the only permitted or if i can obtain my first architectural solution in which the tomcat instances are decoupled from the ESB instances on a third (physically separated) layer.

Answer (score 2):

In image 2, (http://s17.postimg.org/tuy885gzz/Immagine2.png), it is shown a Fail over scenario, where when the Primary ESB node goes down, the requests will be routed to backup node 2.

Even if you want to deploy something like in image 2, you can have the WSO2 AS layer sitting behind the ESB server layer. There you can deploy your REST WS. The REST WS can be fronted by a proxy in your ESB. And the proxy can be accessed by your life ray client.

Comment: So, is it mandatory to have Wso2 AS as clustered application server layer behind the Wso2 ESB? or is it possible to deploy just N Tomcat instances? And what about the load balancer? I mean: the proxy on the esb should have to balance the load on the application server layer (made up of several  clustered application sever), i.e. all the REST service request from the liferay clients layer have to be distributed among the as. In this case, is there a guide telling me how proceed? Thanks